# Max-width: 100% not working on content blocks

Tags: css, css-transitions, responsive, responsive-images

I'm trying to figure out how to display the blocks on this page: https://zadroinc.com/this-is-a-test

I would like the blocks that say `Fogless`, `Vanity`, `Travel`, etc... to shrink to a certain breakpoint rather than just float left when the browser gets smaller. I try setting the max-width of the blocks to 100%, but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions please!!!

Comment: Please post code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, your question title does not match the question body. Are you trying to solve multiple problems at once?

Comment: @MrLister Hi, I edited the posted. What I want is the block categories listed above on https://zadroinc.com/this-is-a-test to shrink down to 800px, then after 800px they will used flexbox for responsiveness.